# Terminal opens with a command not found error

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal, shell

I checked the .bash_profile and .zprofile, but it is empty.
Also .bashrc or .zshrc do not exist in my home directory.

[Terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4hOT.png)

Comment: Include the output of `ls -lad ~/.*`. You probably have a `.history` file or something causing that command to run.

Comment: Check the rest of the zsh startup files. See [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)